# Type dependent macro for printfing hex numbers using token pasting?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'd like to use the same macro for printing different types:

```
int64_t q64 = 0x1234567890ABCDEF;
int32_t q32 = 0x12345678;
int16_t q16 = 0x1234;

PRINT_Q(64, q64);
PRINT_Q(32, q32);
PRINT_Q(16, q16);
```

(There is one more "layer" of abstraction, so I end up with plain `PRINT_Q(name)` macro, without having to specify 64, 32, or 16, but let's simplify here.)

Here is a macro, which I would like to make simpler:

```
#define PRINT_Q(MAXSIZE, name)                              \
    {                                                       \
        if(MAXSIZE==64)                                     \
            printf(" 0x%.016lX ", name);                    \
        else if(MAXSIZE==32)                                \
            printf(" 0x%.08X ", name);                      \
        else if(MAXSIZE==16)                                \
            printf(" 0x%.04X ", name);                      \
    }
```

Is there a way to avoid if-else, and replace `016`, `08`, `04` with `##MAXSIZE` somehow? The question is basically how to go from MAXSIZE which is 64 to 016 as in `0x%.016llX`? And the same for two other cases for MAXSIZE.

Comment: The original code is wrong btw, e.g. `lX` is for `long unsigned integer` only , which `int32_t` cannot be

Comment: @M.M Fixed the code.

Comment: it's not fixed, `int32_t` might be `int` or `long` or `short` or some other type depending on system, whereas `X` is only `unsigned int`

Comment: Could you edit the question?

Comment: not really necessary, we can just say the original code wasn't great either, the answer is still a good answer in either case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard C `_Generic` and drop the size argument. It uses compile-time type checks, so it is as efficient as token pasting but type safe and not as messy:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PRINT_Q(n) printf(  _Generic((n),                 \
                              int64_t: " 0x%.016" PRIX64, \
                              int32_t: " 0x%.08"  PRIX32, \
                              int16_t: " 0x%.04"  PRIX16  \
                            ), (n) )

int main (void)
{
  int64_t q64 = 0x1234567890ABCDEF;
  int32_t q32 = 0x12345678;
  int16_t q16 = 0x1234;

  PRINT_Q(q64);
  PRINT_Q(q32);
  PRINT_Q(q16);
}
```

Output:

```
 0x1234567890ABCDEF 0x12345678 0x1234
```

(Please note however that the `%X` and `%PRIXnn` format specifiers expect an unsigned type as argument. Consider implementing this for unsigned types instead.)

Comment: right idea but wrong specifier (`X64` is for `uint64_t`), perhaps fixing it by casting the argument would be a good plan

Comment: @M.M Indeed, the macro can be rewritten so that it each _Generic clause is a printf and then we can have `uint64_t: printf(" 0x%.016" PRIX64, (n))` as well as  `int64_t: printf(" 0x%.016" PRIX64, (uint64_t)(n))`

Comment: [Documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) for `_Generic`.

Comment: `%.16` same as `%.016` (same as `%.00016`, etc.) and simpler.  `0` right after `.` is not a _zero flag_, just a unnecessary leading digit to the _precision_.  Another common alternative is `%016`.  There `0` is a padding flag.